# WPF program starts process, but does not start properly, load .NET assemblies nor create windows

Tags: wpf

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 WPF application I wrote that works fine on every computer I've tried it on - except on one user's computer (accessed remotely by 2 other people through TeamViewer and LogMeIn respectively) where after double-clicking on the EXE file (or running it from the command-line) the process appears in Task Manager but it doesn't "run" or create any windows. The application's startup code is minimal before execution enters WPF's `Application.Run` method so I'm unsure what's going on.

This is on a Windows 7 SP1 x64 machine with .NET Framework 4.8 installed.

There is nothing relevant logged in any of the Windows event logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Microsoft's [Sysinternals Suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) on the computer to use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (`ProcExp`) and [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (`ProcMon`) to see what the process was actually doing while it was sitting there, doing nothing.

ProcExp revealed that the process had not loaded any .NET Assemblies into itself despite being a .NET process - which suggests something was breaking during the CLR initialization process (as the `mscorlib.dll` assembly should be loaded before anything else).

I killed the process, then ran ProcMon to monitor the process as it started, and started a new instance of the program - ProcMon showed the process initially loading and reading system files as normal - but for some reason I saw it then loaded `C:\Users\$userName\AppData\Local\LogMeIn Rescue Applet\lmirhook.001.dll` - and then the process started loading other native DLLs from `SysWow64` that my process does not normally load that are related to Windows' internet stack which I assume LogMeIn was loading.

I noticed that the computer had two simultaneous, concurrent installs of LogMeInRescue running (or at least, had two entries in Computer Management > Services with different GUIDs in the name).

I stopped both LogMeIn Rescue sessions which meant they both did an immediate self-uninstall of LogMeIn Rescue. After verifying that LogMeIn Rescue was no longer present on the computer I saw that my program now started running without any problems and loaded the .NET Framework, .NET assemblies and created the windows as-expected.

I then re-opened LogMeIn Rescue from their website - only running a single instance of LogMeIn Rescue (instead of the two instances that were running when the problem existed) and my program also ran fine.

So apparently each LogMeIn Rescue instance attempts to inject its own native code into every process and it stalls, presumably because each instance's injected code conflicts with the other instance's for some reason, and this then stops the rest of the process from doing anything, so it sits there idle (I suspect it causes the main thread to abort, but creates another thread that's blocked so Windows never kills the process because the other thread isn't marked as a background-thread (as Windows never kills processes with non-background threads, even if those threads are blocked).

#### TL;DR:

Make sure there aren't 2 or more instances of LogMeIn Rescue running on the computer. If so, remove them both, try again, and allow only 1 instance back.